# TypeError: Cannot read property 'stimulus' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I have a program that shows a slideshow of pictures. When the picture is shown on the screen, I have `this` logged to the console. So, we then have the `this` object printed to the console: [Photo of entire this object printed to console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s2sy.png)

I want to access and print the `stimulus` property to the console, however when I try to `console.log(this.stimulus)`, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property stimulus of undefined`. Why can I not access this property?

EDIT: Forgot to add the misbehaving code:

```
    stimulus: 'stimulus',
    type: "callbackImageKeyboardResponsePlugin",
    timeline: targets,
    on_start: function() {
      console.log(this.stimulus)
    },
    trial_duration: function () {
      return jsPsych.randomization.sampleWithoutReplacement(
        [250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750],
        1
      )[0];
    },
    stimulus_duration: stim_duration,
    post_trial_gap: post_trial_gap(),
    
  };
```

EDIT: Here is where on_start is being called I believe... it is part of a plugin from a package I am using:

```
      trial.on_start.call();
    } else if (typeof trial.on_start !== "undefined") {
      trial.data["on_start"] = trial.on_start;
    }
```

Comment: Probably because of arrow function misuse. Show us some of that code?

Comment: @AKX forgot to add that picture, sorry!

Comment: Agreed we need some code. Either an arrow function malforming or an array out of bound

Comment: How are you calling on_start()? Please share that code too.

Comment: IMAGES OF CODE ARE USELESS. We can not copy and paste text from an image.

Comment: `console.log(this);`

Comment: I have added the code as text, sorry about that! Still learning the ins/outs of posting.

Comment: `trial.on_start.call()` will unset the "this" in the on_start function.  Either use `trial.on_start()` or `trial.on_start.call(trial)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is not a toy, don't use it without reason and when you use it, use it properly

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.
>
> [...]
>
> If the method is a function in non-strict mode, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be converted to objects.

That's what `trial.on_start.call()` does not, specifying a `this` parameter, and apparently your code ran in strict mode:

```js
function test() {
  "use strict";
  const myobj = {
    x: function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  };

  myobj.x();              // <-- this is how normally you call a method, just ()
  myobj.x.call();         // <-- the one producing undefined
  myobj.x.call(myobj);    // <-- overcomplicated, but works again
}
test();
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I will be careful when using `call()`!